# J2ME Web Service Providers

Tags: web-services, java-me, mobile-phones

I have read that it is possible to send HTTP/SOAP messages to web service using kSOAP. But is it possible in a J2ME app to receive HTTP/SOAP messages? I.e. the mobile app acting like a web service provider? How is it done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://javaswamy.blogspot.com/2003/09/j2me-turning-your-phone-into-web.html) shows you how it can be done, but by the looks of it, you are just mimicking a webserver.